# FIWARE CEP (Proton) REST ouput authentication error

Tags: activemq-classic, basic-authentication, fiware, complex-event-processing, fiware-cep

I'm training to send an output event from FIWARE CEP (Proton), using the REST consumer, to an ActiveMQ queue. The credential for access the ActiveMQ queue are included in the URL, as http://user:passwrd@X.X.X.X:xxxx/api/message/myqueue, but I have the following error:

> com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.resources.EventResource submitNewEvent
>   INFO: events sent to proton runtime...
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
>   INFO: basic authentication scheme selected
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processWWWAuthChallenge
>   INFO: No credentials available for BASIC 'ActiveMQRealm'@X.X.X.X
>   com.ibm.hrl.proton.server.executorServices.SimpleThreadFactory$ProtonExceptionHandler uncaughtException
>   SEVERE: Uncaught exception in thread: Thread[4,5,main],exception: com.ibm.hrl.proton.adapters.rest.client.RESTException: com.ibm.hrl.proton.adapters.rest.client.RESTException: Could not perform POST of event instance: ...
>   with request headers:
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>   User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0
>   Host: X.X.X.X:xxxx
>   Content-Length: 389
>   to consumer http://user:passwrd@X.X.X.X:xxx/api/message/myqueue, responce result: 401

Seems like that Proton doesn't extract the credential from the URL.
Anyone else had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the CEP REST consumer definition an AuthToken parameter.

From the CEP user guide (can be found [here](https://github.com/ishkin/Proton/tree/master/documentation)):

> AuthToken – an optional parameter. When set, it is added as an X-Auth-Token
>   HTTP header of the request.